# How much GUI real-estate is available for a wearable app to customize notifications?

Tags: android, wear-os

When my mobile app posts a notification if there is a paired wearable then only the small icon and notification title are displayed on a small band at the bottom of the wearable (and the user has to swipe to reveal more content, in my case I have a LG watch I'm experimenting with).

I'd like for both the notification title ANS some content text to be visible on the wearable when the notification is displayed without the user having to swipe to see any text other than the title. I know I can write an app to install on the wearable to customize the display, but I couldn't find out any information about any size restrictions etc. If I write a wearable app can it increase the size of the notification displayed on the wearable larger than that displayed by default?

Answer (score 0):

Here on the Android Dev website there is a guide to create custom notifications:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications

It may be more work than it's worth but I think that guide has what you need.